# How to bind 2 textboxes to one property?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have a propery `PhoneNumber` and in the UI, I have 2 textboxes, one is the prefix, and the other one is the postfix, how can I bind it to the property? (The property inside the DataContext).

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="3" /> //Prefix
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="-" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" /> //Postfix
```

[image]

The only way I see it work is with code behind using textbox1.Text + textbox2.Text... Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Blam I think you didn't understand the question. The problem is not how to bind, but how to bind two textboxes into one property? It's not a regular binding and it's not MultiBinding too.

Comment: @Blam Have you read my post? I also have written what I have tried.

Comment: Way I see and try are not the same thing.  I understand the problem.  textbox1.Text + textbox2.Text is not binding and that is why I commented with the link to binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use two more properties in the data context

code is not complied or tested

```
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public string Prefix
{
    get
    {
        return PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 3);
    }
    set
    {
        // replace the first three chars of PhoneNumber
        PhoneNumber = value + PhoneNumber.Substring(3);
    }
}
public string Postfix
{
    get
    {
        return PhoneNumber.Substring(3);
    }
    set
    { 
        // replace the  chars of starting from index 3 of PhoneNumber
        PhoneNumber =  PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 3) + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, You are right - it will be easier comparing to my solution with Converters.

Comment: @Romasz-I was missing the setter part which is added now

Comment: Looks nice. The OP will have only to parse his PhoneNumber correctly (with/wthout semicolon or other formats).

Answer (score 2):

I think uou can use Converter for this purpose, the example going one way can look like this:

In this my Number is a `string` 000-000000, but you can surely change it.

In XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:PostixConverter x:Key="PostfixConv" xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Example.Converters"/>
    <conv:PrefixConverter x:Key="PrefixConv" xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Example.Converters"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>     
    <TextBox  MaxLength="3" Text="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource PrefixConv}}"/> 
    <TextBlock  Text="-" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource PostfixConv}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And in code behind:

```
namespace Example.Converters
{
  public class PrefixConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        else return ((string)value).Substring(0, 3);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }

  public class PostixConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
        if (value == null) return null;
        else return ((string)value).Substring(4);
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
}
```